# Why are there 'Int's **and** 'Double's? Why not just have one class?

Tags: scala, int, double

So I know this may be a very naive question, but I'm new to Scala and other similar languages, and this legitimately befuddles me.

Why does Scala (and other languages) have two distinct classes for integers and doubles? Since integers are in floats `(1.0 = 1)`, why bother with an Int class?

I sort of understand that maybe you want to make sure that some integers are never changed into floats, or that maybe you want to guard against occurrences like `1.00000000002 != 1`, which may be confusing when you only see the first few digits, but is there some other underlying justification that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: because sometimes an int is appropriate and sometimes a double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers are important to the internal workings of software, because many things are internally implemented as integers that you wouldn't necessarily think of as "numbers". For example, memory addresses are generally represented as integers; individual eight-bit bytes are generally conceived of as one-byte integers; and characters (such as ASCII characters and Unicode characters) are usually identified by integer-valued codepoints. (In all of these cases, incidentally, in the rare event that we want to display them, we generally use hexadecimal notation, which is convenient because it uses exactly two characters per eight-bit byte.) Another important case, that usually *is* thought of as numeric even outside programming, is array indices; even in math, an array of length three will have elements numbered 1, 2, and 3 (though in programming, many languages — including Scala — will use the indices 0, 1, and 2 instead, sometimes because of the underlying scheme for mapping indices to memory addresses, and sometimes due to historical reasons relating to older languages' doing so for this reason).

More generally, many things in computing (and in the real world) are strictly quantized; it doesn't make sense to write of "[2.4](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/2.4_children) table rows", or "2.4 loop iterations", so it's convenient to have a data-type where arithmetic is exact, and represents exact integer quantities.

But you're right that the distinction is not absolutely essential; a number of scripting languages, such as Perl and JavaScript and Tcl, have mostly dispensed with the explicit distinction between integers and floating-point numbers (though the distinction is still often drawn in the workings of the interpreters, with conversions occurring implicitly when needed). For example, in JavaScript, `typeof 3` and `typeof 3.0` are both `'number'`.

Answer (score 3):

Integers are generally much easier to work with given that they have exact representations.  This is true not only at the software level, but at the hardware level as well.  For example, looking at [this source describing the x86 architecture](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), floating point addition generally takes 4X longer than integer addition.  As such, it is advantageous to separate the two types of operations for performance reasons as well as usability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other two answers, integers are *not* actually in floats. That is, there are some integers which can't be represented exactly by a float:

```
scala> Int.MaxValue.toFloat == (Int.MaxValue - 1).toFloat
res0: Boolean = true
```

Same for longs and doubles.